# How do I iterate over dictionary list positions in python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, iteration

Hi I have a dictionary where the values are lists.

```
position = {"a" :[0,0], "b":[0,100], "c":[50,100], "d": [50, 0]}
```

I'm inserting each dictionary value into a handler.

```
poly_pos = [position["a"], position["b"], position["c"], position["d"]]
```

I want to iterate over the dictionary list and add value to the 0th element of each list position.

For instance for `position["a"][0]` I want to add 50, and for every subsequent `["letter"][0]` element of each list in the dictionary I want to add 50.

If this isn't the best way to solve this, I'm curious to know other ways I can solve, maybe without using dictionary value pairs.

Comment: (1) What have you tried to achieve this? please post your code; (2) defaultdict may help you in working with these structures; (3) ChainMap may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position.values()` gives the same thing as your definition of `poly_pos`:

```
for p in position.values():
    p[0] += 50
```

You can also use `position.itervalues()` to avoid creating the list if you're using Python 2.